# AttributeError: no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python

When i run the coding in this `yolo_opencv.py` file :

The console shows this error:

> File "", line 40, in 
>      Width = image.shape[1]
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: It's impossible to tell what `image` is supposed to be without seeing your code. However it currently is defined as `None` which does not have an attribute called `shape` as the error states. You might wanna add the part of the code that defines `image`.

Comment: I added the part of the code that defines the specific image i want, the yolo_opencv.py file that includes these shape error is already implemented from the source and it's downloaded with the YOLO weights from the source, so the code that gave this error is from the source.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give some advice. You could/should describe your problem a bit more clear. I just Googled the file you mentioned `yolo_opencsv.py` and its part of Object detection (YOLO, SSD, Faster R-CNN) with OpenCV and Python library. It always a good idea to mention the tool/library you are using (and are having problems with) in the title. Also you could/describe the procedure and environment you are using when the error occurs. By doing so, people can try to replicate you problem and have to ask less additional questions trying to help you solve the problem.

Your error seems to indicate that the image object has not loaded properly, i.e. the return of `cv2.imread(args.image)` has returned `None`. Do you run the command from the command line as described in the README. And are you sure you image path and image format is correct?

Comment: I ran the command line as described in the README exactly. I'm sure that I did every step exactly as mentioned in the part of object detection in Github.
Below is the code, it's already found as a .py file in the YOLO weights downloaded from the website, I corrected some type errors in the code by the help of stack overflow, but the error of no attribute shape I didn't find any help to resolve it, the code is here below:


import cv2
import argparse
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(args.image)

Width = image.shape[416]
Height = image.shape[416]
scale = 0.00392

Comment: I'm working with Python for this project, and I checked the image path, the image objects were not loaded properly, thank you.